# Formatting an XML

Tags: python, xml, bash

I have a huge xml which i will have to process everyday in hive using xpath.
Since xpath doesn't work well with comments and namespaces, I am looking for a bash / python script to remove the same.

The number of tags and the number of comment lines will not be constant everyday,
so i can't use a constant identity xslt for this . Also tidy isn't present ,so thats not an option for me.

Any guidance on parsing this with bash or python would be helpful.

Sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<tag1 xmlns:xsi="--dummy--" xmlns="--dummy---">

<tag2>

<!-- Default Codec Profile -->

    <configitem name="att1" type="string">attval</configitem>
</tag2>
```

Comment: But XPATH does work well with comments and namespaces. Why remove them? You considered XSLT to strip them but then XSLT is XPATH based so you didn't really fix the problem.

Comment: xpath functions in hive are not extracting tag values when namespaces and comments are there. May be thats not added yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)'s format function. Huge amounts of XML can be reformatted or pretty printed quickly with the `xml fo` invocation.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me to remove the comments perfectly. Working on it to remove version and namespace info.